# How to wrap exceptions handling in helper class with lambda expressions

Tags: java, exception, lambda

I am having troubles while trying to refactor exception handling logic in an helper class.

My code uses a repository which accesses a database and might throw the custom exception `RepositoryException`. If such exception is thrown by the repository, I want my code to catch it and set an error label in the graphical user interface (`view`):

```java
... // more code
try {
    existingCourse = repository.findByTitle(course.getTitle());  // <- throws RepositoryException
} catch (RepositoryException e) {
    view.showError(e.getMessage(), course);
    return;
}
... // some more code
```

The point is that this code is repeated several times and I would prefer to have it refactored in an helper class. 
This is what I came up to after some experiments:

- A custom `FunctionalInterface` called `ThrowingSupplier`, which represent the code that throws the exception.
- A `TransactionManager` helper class, with a `catcher` methods that accepts a `ThrowingSupplier`

This is the related code (`BaseEntity` is just a base class for entities in my domain, as you might guess):

```java
// ThrowingSupplier.java
@FunctionalInterface
public interface ThrowingSupplier<T extends BaseEntity> {
    T get() throws RepositoryException;
}

/* ------------------------------------------------------ */

// ExceptionManager.java
public final class ExceptionManager<T extends BaseEntity> {

    private T result;
    private String exceptionMessage;

    ExceptionManager() {
    }

    public boolean catcher(ThrowingSupplier<T> supplier) {
        try {
            clearResult();
            clearExceptionMessage();
            result = supplier.get();
            return true;
        } catch (RepositoryException e) {
            exceptionMessage = e.getMessage();
        }
        return false;
    }

    // public getters and 'clearers' for attributes
    ...

}
```

And this is how I am using this now:

```java
...
em = new ExceptionManager();
... // more code
if (!em.catcher(() -> repository.findByTitle(course.getTitle()))) {
    view.showError(em.getExceptionMessage(), course);
    return;
}
existingCourse = em.getResult();
... // some more code
```

Now it seems to me that this does not give any advantages with respect to using directly the try catch in every repository invocation. This is mainly because I need both the return value of the repository method and a way to tell the caller if the repository call has been successful. As a variation I tried to add the `showError` call inside catcher, but then I must pass `view` and `entity` in every invocation of `catcher`, which I do not like very much as it makes the code less readable.

Is there another way to accomplish this in an elegant manner or it is better to leave the try catch in every call to the repository? Also, what is the standard way to deal with this problem?

Comment: I wonder, why are you using lambdas in the first place? What is the benefit you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I am using lambdas because i can pass any expression I want in that lambda, to be executed in the try/catch block inside the method `catcher`: more specifically I can pass any method of my repository, e.g. `repository.findById()`, `repository.save()`, `repository.delete()`, etc.

Comment: Yes, but you can pass any expression in a try-catch block too... I mean, lambda-expression have indeed their place in refactoring, when you can pass them into higher order functions. What is, in your case, the point of passing a lambda-expression into a "try-catch wrapping" `ExceptionManager`? What purpose does it serve in your design? What pattern does it help abstract? Ciao ;-)

Comment: The original point was to avoid repeating the same lines of code in the file: as every access to the repository can potentially throw a `RepositoryException`, I wanted to avoid repeating the try/catch for the exception. Unfortunately, in the end it seems that the code to abstract the exception handling mechanism adds too much boilerplate code, and the original try/catch approach seems better to me right now. Thank you for your commitment. Grazie!